# What does it mean "...blood that will be shed by many of you for the forgiveness of sins"?

Tags: catholicism, life-of-jesus, communion, mass, eucharistic-adoration

The priest during Mass, always says this while on the Eucharist, Holy communion time, when the bell rings, and one kneels.

What exactly does this mean for people?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phrase you quoted is part of what Jesus said to His apostles at the Last Supper, when He instituted the Eucharist. The part about "shed for the forgiveness of sins" is Jesus's prediction of what was going to happen the next day at Calvary.

Comment: "Eucharist" that's a better description, I've edited my post.

Comment: Yes I know it's what Jesus said to his apostles. But after that, he said "…blood that will be shed for the forgiveness of sins?" referring not to him but to people, AFAIU. And what's the meaning?

Comment: Jesus is referring to *His own* blood, which will be shed when He is scourged and crucified, for the forgiveness of *our* sins.

Comment: No, the priest says both statements that  Jesus said: that would pass through what he passed through (AFAIU). And right after that he _says_: "and blood that will be shed by several of you for the forgiveness of sins". Sorry I'm going to edit again  to clarify.

Comment: If the priest says, during the consecration, "the blood that will be shed *by several of you* for the forgiveness of sins" then the consecration is invalid, and I'm not going to guess what such a priest might have in mind.

Comment: Yes he says that. And since the first time I heard it, I was like: what?? and today I was done with that statement.

Comment: I'll pay more more attention next time, but I really doubt that I'd have heard  wrong, such statement, plenty of times.

Comment: If I remember correctly (from when I attended English masses), the words of consecration of the wine were "This is the cup of My blood, the blood of the new and everlasting covenant. It will be shed for you and for many unto the remission of sins." (Actually, in those days, they said "for all", but that has since been corrected to "for many".)

Comment: There it is. That's "different" to what the priest says, but I think it's not his fault, I've checked how it's translated to Spanish: "Será derramada por vosotros y por muchos para remisión de los pecados" it's what the priest says and it can be interpreted as "it'll be shed from you and from many of you for the forgiveness of sins". Specially that last part. But seeing the English version, this short words: "for you and for many" that explains it all. That clearly says that is Jesus who was going to do that for us.

Comment: Thank you so much for the clarification:) have a very nice day/night.

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if the quotation you used is correct? You wrote, "...blood that will be shed by many of you for the forgiveness of sins."

There are different Bible translations of this passage, but all I have seen are clear that Jesus was referring to His own blood being poured out for many for the forgiveness of sins. You may not have quoted the priest correctly.

[Matthew 26:27-28 GNT](https://biblehub.com/gntd/matthew/26.htm):

*27Then he took a cup, gave thanks to God, and gave it to them. “Drink it, all of you,” he said; 28 “this is my blood, which seals God's covenant, **my blood poured out for many for the forgiveness of sins**. *

[Matthew 26:27-28 Doay-Rheims](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew%2026&version=NIV):

*27 Then he took a cup, and when he had given thanks, he gave it to them, saying, “Drink from it, all of you. 28 **This is my blood** of the[b] covenant, which is poured out for many for the forgiveness of sins.*

Comment: It was a misunderstanding from my part on not knowing about the history of Jesus (I knew part)+ translations to Spanish.  The thing is that, the priest always says "...Sangre de la alianza nueva y eterna que será derramada por ustedes y por muchos para el perdón de los pecados". See?